# open cam without user permission in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, web-applications, webcam

how to open camera without user permission in react-webcam and when the user turn it off close the page

```
function Quiz1page1() {
const webRef=useRef(null);
const webStyle={
  position:'relative',left:'600px',top:'300px'
}

return (
  <div className='Content'>
    <fieldset className='bg-light  '>
      <p className='question  p-2' > What is the capital of England?</p>      
<input className='answers' type="text" id="text" name="fav_language" />
</fieldset>

<Link to="/Quiz1page2">
<button id='SubmitBtn' className='Next btn btn-dark mt-3 btn'>Next</button>
</Link>
<Webcam style={webStyle}  audio={false} width={350} refs={webRef} />
<br/>
  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on most of the devices configuration.
Fortunately because that is an privacy violation act

Comment: Ok thanks how to close page if the user not allow camera to open(I can do it?)

Comment: Ask a new question because idk how to do that